# Why didn't Rios tell Picard he had been to the Vayt System on the ibn Majid?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-picard

When Rios talked to Rafi about what happened on the ibn Majid in *Picard* season 1, he said they had traveled way out to the Vayt system. Did he not realize what that meant when they agreed to take Soji home? What would they have done without the Borg portals?

Comment: Can you provide more context to the question? I'm having trouble understanding what you are asking.